# beamercolorbox with transparency creates a darker horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I try to make a transparent beamercolorbox (or any transparent box) but always get a horizontal line that is a bit darker than the rest of the box. Is there a way to get it to go away? I took the example from [Where can I find beamercolorbox options defined?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277268/where-can-i-find-beamercolorbox-options-defined) and adapted to

```
    \documentclass[dvipsnames]{beamer}
    \usetheme{Copenhagen}
    \setbeamercolor{mycolor}{fg=RoyalBlue,bg=red}
    \begin{document}
       \begin{frame}
       \pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,rounded=true]{mycolor}%
        colored text
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \end{frame} 

    \end{document}
```

But I get a box that looks like this[image: beamercolorbox not as I want it]

How do I get rid of the red horizontal line at the top of the box?

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317489/untitled-block-transparency-beamer

Comment: if you need to create boxes have a look at the `tcolorbox` package too, which offers much more flexibility than a `beamercolorbox`